# Echo two set /p

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I made a bat that renames folders
and files inside them
it asks for the old name
and then new name
like

```
SET /p originalcodename="Please enter the ORIGINAL codename: "
SET /p newcodename="Please enter the NEW codename: "
```

and I made anohter bat for bulk processes
and its like this

```
echo example_oldfoldername| renamecodename.bat (
echo example_newfoldername| renamecodename.bat|rem
)
```

and it gave bunch of errors
I wonder if there is a way to make it echo two inputs
it's a bit complicated but

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide both inputs to the same instance of your batch file:

```
(echo example_oldfoldername&echo example_newfoldername)| renamecodename.bat
```

or to keep it readable in a batch file:

```
(
  echo example_oldfoldername
  echo example_newfoldername
) | renamecodename.bat
```

Pay attention to any stray spaces, they are invisible but will get part of the variables, which may lead to unexpected behaviour.

Comment: thank you but the second script got spaces in it. like `folders\newfoldername \images`

Comment: only when you put them into the `echo` statements. (that's why I added the last sentence)

Comment: `(echo foo & echo bar )` will include both spaces, `(echo foo&echo bar)` will not. With the second (batch file) solution take care not to have spaces after the strings.

Comment: i tried what you said and it detects the original foldername, leaves a space after it and doesnt detect the new folder name. it doesnt work

Comment: As you didn't pipe `\images` to the batch script, I would suggest that it, and possibly the rogue space character, is being appended in `renamecodename.bat`. Please edit your question to include the content of `renamecodename.bat`, if you want us to assist you further.

Comment: I have the same suspicion as @Compo. If you did as you said, there can't be spaces in the received parameters.